# Why is Ruby not available to me after compiling from source?

Tags: ruby, compilation

I'm trying to compile Ruby 2.0 from source onto Debian stable. I'm following [the steps in the chruby wiki](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/wiki/Ruby) since I'd like to use chruby to manage my ruby versions (installed it prior to this). So, I ran these commands in a subdirectory of my home directory:

```
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p247
./configure --prefix=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247
make
sudo make install
```

Afterwards, I ran `ruby -v` to see if everything went ok, and get a message from the shell: `bash: ruby: command not found`. Then I ran `make check` in the ruby directory and received this output:

```
ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
check succeeded
```

What went wrong here?

Comment: Did you check your path and that the install put it in a directory that's in your path? Many builds from source will put he command in `/opt/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. If you want it installed somewhere else, there may be make options to do so.

Comment: are you required to compile from source? why not rvm?

Comment: Do a `locate ruby` and see if you can find where it put the binaries. They're probably not in your path, as @mbratch pointed out.

Comment: @mohawkjohn I ran `locate ruby` but don't see any binaries; just filenames that have ruby in them in /usr/share. Get no output for running `which ruby`.

Comment: `which ruby` will only identify rubies in your path. Try doing `updatedb` and then running `locate ruby` again.

Comment: @mbratch There aren't any ruby files in my /usr/local/bin. What has to be copied there to run ruby? The whole directory created from the .tar.gz file or just the binaries?

Comment: It may not be in `/usr/local/bin` it might be somewhere else. Is all the source under `/usr/local`?

Comment: @mohawkjohn Ok, ran `sudo updatedb` and got a large output for `locate ruby`. Running `ruby -v` still results in the same error, though.

Comment: @mbratch I unpacked all the source files in my home directory. Are they supposed to belong in a different place in the filesystem?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just that to me it's unclear what it chooses for default `bin` in that case. Have you checked any README or doc files came with the source package? Normally it would say.

Comment: I noticed in the documentation you pointed to, it has the line, `./configure --prefix=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247`. What did you use for your `./configure` parameter?

Comment: `locate ruby` doesn't change your path. It just tells you where `ruby` might be so you can add it to your path. Try out each one that looks like it might be a binary (run it with the `-v` flag) and see if it's your installed version. Then you can do `ln -s /path/to/ruby /usr/bin/ruby` which should put it in the correct place. Try `which ruby` to confirm.

Comment: @mbratch I used the same paramater for ./configure as the one in the chruby wiki.

Comment: Then see the answer @CodyCaughlan just gave. That prefix option tells the build where to put outputs.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but `chruby` gives you installation instructions with that `--prefix` value because that's where `chruby` itself looks for Ruby versions. The prefix is somewhere that's not on `$PATH` **on purpose**, since you're meant to be using `chruby` to manage which one is available. That specific document is not meant to be a general-purpose guide to installing Ruby systemwide.

Comment: Oop. Good point. Somehow I missed that part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin` in your `$PATH`? With a `--prefix` like that then `make install` will put all the binaries in `$prefix/bin` basically.

If you do

```
$ ls /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

You'll see all your binaries

Comment: Yes, that directory wasn't in my $PATH! Further down in the chruby documentation there was mention of a script that you run to configure this whenever you open a shell. Following that did the trick and `echo $PATH` shows that the directory in question was added. Thank you. All so obvious in retrospect, huh...